# How to use a loop to rerun a basic calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I'm very new to programming and as a student mathematics I'm going to follow Python programming. To be well prepared I thought I would already dive into the program, using some youtube videos and online material. Now the question.

I'm building a basic calculator. It works fine for the three functions I described in it. But if someone mistyped the function he or she wants to use (for example typed "multifly" i.s.o "multiply") it returns a sentence telling the user it has made a typo. I want to represent this line but also let it rerun from the start. That is, if you made a typo, to get back to line 1 asking the user what he wants to do.

I know I have to use a for or a while loop but I have no idea how actually to get it in, working. Please give me some advice :)

```
choice = input("Welcome to the basic calculator, please tell me if you want to add, substract or muliply: ")

if choice == "add":

     print("You choose to add")
     input_1 = float(input("Now give me your first number: "))
     input_2 = float(input("And now the second: "))
     result = (input_1 + input_2)
     if (result).is_integer() == True:
          print("Those two added makes " + str(int(result)))
     else:
          print("Those two added makes " + str(result))
elif choice == "substract":
     print("You choose to substract")
     input_1 = float(input("Now give me your first number: "))
     input_2 = float(input("And now the second: "))
     result = (input_1 - input_2)
     if (result).is_integer() == True:
          print("Those two substracted makes " + str(int(result)))
     else:
         print("Those two substracted makes " + str(result))
elif choice == "multiply":
     print("You choose to multiply")
     input_1 = float(input("Now give me your first number: "))
     input_2 = float(input("And now the second: "))
     result = (input_1 * input_2)
     if (result).is_integer() == True:
         print("Those two multiplied makes " + str(int(result)))
     else:
         print("Those two multiplied makes " + str(result))

else:
print("I think you made a typo, you'd have to try again.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
choices={"add","substract","multiply"}
while 1:
    choice = input("Welcome to the basic calculator, please tell me if you want to add, substract or muliply: ")
    if choice not in choices:
        print("I think you made a typo, you'd have to try again.")
    else: break

if choice == "add":
    ...
```

You do the input and verification part in the loop, then your code with the calculating. (Assuming the calculator only calculates once and then exits. If not, you could put the whole thing in another loop for more calculations, with maybe an exit command.)

In my example, verification is done with a set (choices) containing your possible commands, and checking for membership of the input.

Comment: Why would you need the line: choice= "" ?

Comment: Because the calculation part of your code does checks on it, so it needs to exist outside the verification loop. EDIT: Oh, it actually doesn't, just checked. C++ would flip for this, guess too used to that. TIL.

Answer (score 1):

```
OP = ("add", "subtract", "multiply")

while True:
    choice = input("Pick an operation {}: ".format(OP))
    if choice not in OP:
        print("Invalid input")
    else:
        break

if choice == OP[0]:
#...
```